# Mulitline headline for csv in Spark

Tags: csv, apache-spark, hadoop, hdfs

I need Spark to write a compressed csv file to HDFS, but I need it to start with a few lines of version information.

Example of file content

```
version=2
date=2020-01-31

id,name,age
1,Alice,21
2,Bob,23
```

**Three ideas of ways to do this**

1. First write out to hdfs://data/tmp/file1.csv.gz, then use hadoop fs -cat
   to stream it to hdfs://data/real/file1.csv.gz
2. Convert output
   datafram to text format / `RDD[String]` and union real file with the
   extra header lines
3. Change the first column name to multi line

So for approach 3:

`column1 ="version=2\ndate=2020-01-31\n\nid"`

Let me know if you know a more elegant way to do this.

Comment: No 2 sounds good to me. You will loose schema derivation which can be easily provided by your code.

Comment: Why use csv at all? You could encode this data just as easily in json/avro/parquet, which Hadoop handles just as well

Comment: @cricket_007 thanks. I am saving both in parquet and in csv. The csv file is for a client.

Comment: But the file with headers like you've shown is not truly CSV, by definition. If you want metadata, then provide it via a separate file and GZIP them together

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the approaches. Here is simplified code:

**Approach 1**

Approach 1 is using Hadoop commands from a bash script etc.

This works, but requires a double HDFS write and a cleanup. Also it doesn't fit so well in a Scala Spark project.

```sh
(echo -e "version=2\ndate=2020-01-31\n\nid,name,age" | gzip  -vc ; hadoop fs -cat "$INPUT_DIR/*" ) | hadoop fs -put - "$OUTPUT_PATH"
```

What is happening here is that it will

1. echo multi line header out to stdout
2. pipe that into gzip and to stdout
3. pipe other HDSF dir to stdout
4. pipe into `hadoop fs -put` that will combine everything

**Approach 2**

Code is a little more complicated there are not bad quote characters in headline, but headlines sometimes come after csv part.

```scala
import org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec

val heading = """version=2
date=2020-01-31

id,name,age""".split("\n", -1).toSeq

val headingRdd: RDD[String] = sc.parallelize(heading)

val mediamathRdd: RDD[String] = df.rdd.map(row => row.mkString(","))

val combinedResult: RDD[String] = (headingRdd union mediamathRdd)

combinedResult.repartition(1).saveAsTextFile(path, classOf[GzipCodec])
```

**Approach 3**

The simplest approach, but the output is slightly off

```scala
df.repartition(1)
.withColumnRenamed("id", "version=2\ndate=2020-01-31\n\nid")
.option("header", true)
.option("delimiter", ",")
.option("quoteMode", "NONE")
.option("quote", " ")
.option("codec", "gzip")
.csv(path)
```

Result will look like this, which might or might not be acceptable

```
 version=2
date=2020-01-31

id ,name,age
1,Alice,21
2,Bob,23
```

I also tried with:

`.option("quote", "\u0000")`

It actually prints the ascii charter zero and while this did not show up in my HDFS viewer this was not part of the spec.

**Best Approach**

None of them are perfect for what seems like a very simple task. Maybe there is a small fix to make approach 2 work perfectly.